# Flutter: Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget and inner listview is not fully visible

Tags: flutter

I am working on a `nested listview` in flutter, I did it like below.

```
class _SearchResultState extends State<SearchResult> {
  late String searchValue;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    searchValue = widget.searchValue;
    searchData = widget.searchValue;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SearchBox(),
              WordDetails(),
              const SizedBox(height: 5),
              DictionaryUsersList(),
              WordMeaning(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}

class WordMeaning extends StatelessWidget {
  WordMeaning({super.key});

  final json = <Map<String, dynamic>>[
    {
      'type': 'adjective',
      'meaning': [
        {
          'description': 'description 1',
          'example': 'example 1',
        },
        {
          'description': 'description 2',
          'example': 'example 2',
        },
        {
          'description': 'description 3',
          'example': 'example 3',
        },
        {
          'description': 'description 4',
          'example': 'example 4',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      'type': 'noun',
      'meaning': [
        {
          'description': 'description 1',
          'example': 'example 1',
        },
        {
          'description': 'description 2',
          'example': 'example 2',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      'type': 'verb',
      'meaning': [
        {
          'description': 'description 1',
          'example': 'example 1',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      'type': 'adverb',
      'meaning': [
        {
          'description': 'description 1',
          'example': 'example 1',
        },
        {
          'description': 'description 2',
          'example': 'example 2',
        },
        {
          'description': 'description 3',
          'example': 'example 3',
        },
      ],
    },
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Word> words = json.map((json) => Word.fromJson(json)).toList();

    return NestedListView(data: words);
  }
}

class NestedListView extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Word> data;

  const NestedListView({
    Key? key,
    required this.data,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Expanded(
          child: SizedBox(
            child: ListView.builder(
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: data.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                List<Meaning> innerList = data[index].meaning;
                return Expanded(
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 80,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                          child: Text(data[index].type.toString().toUpperCase()),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: ListView.builder(
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            itemCount: innerList.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              final product = innerList[index];
                              return Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                                child: Container(
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                    child: Column(
                                      children: [
                                        Text(product.description),
                                        Text(product.example),
                                      ],
                                    )),
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have 2 issues with this UI.

1. The inner listview is not fully visible. Please check the below screenshot.

[image]

2. Getting below error when running the application:

> ======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
> The following assertion was thrown while applying parent data.:
> Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.

> The ParentDataWidget Expanded(flex: 1) wants to apply ParentData of type FlexParentData to a RenderObject, which has been set up to accept ParentData of incompatible type ParentData.

> Usually, this means that the Expanded widget has the wrong ancestor RenderObjectWidget. Typically, Expanded widgets are placed directly inside Flex widgets.
> The offending Expanded is currently placed inside a RepaintBoundary widget.

I tried wrapping the `Expanded` widget with a `Column` like below:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: SizedBox(
            child: ListView.builder(
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: data.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                List<Meaning> innerList = data[index].meaning;
                return SizedBox(
                  height: 80,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                        child: Text(data[index].type.toString().toUpperCase()),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: SizedBox(
                          height: 80,
                          child: ListView.builder(
                            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            itemCount: innerList.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              final product = innerList[index];
                              return Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                                child: Container(
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: [
                                      Text(product.description),
                                      Text(product.example),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

But at that time getting another error like below:

> ======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
> The following assertion was thrown during paint():
> RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#50ab9 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT
> 'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
> Failed assertion: line 1966 pos 12: 'hasSize'

> Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've used `Expanded` widget in `ListView` and in `SingleScrollChildView`, it is only applicable in `Row` and `Column`. Simply remove `Expanded` from these and it will be fixed.

Comment: I have tried removing the `Expanded`, but again getting `RenderBox was not laid out:` error.

Comment: I have created a demo with my code, could you please check. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z9IfAFEGUhv4FGmrIQp5KFAeHO6hiXNb/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This is because you have infinite height in a vertical widget. i.e. You have used `SingleScrollChildView` and you have Column along with Expanded in it, please remove this Expanded. As SingleScrollChildView scrolls to infinite vertical view @SreejithSree

Comment: I removed the expanded under `SingleChildScrollView`, but same error after that. https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GYll.png

Comment: What I mean is to remove all Expanded in any kinda of scrolling widget, e.g. you still have on in your ListView.builder. That is a scrolling widget too

Answer (score 1):

The more you go nested, the more complex is to handle the UI. Try to modify like below. You need to do fourchanges.

1. Remove `SingleChildScrollView`, `Expanded`, `SizedBox` and keep it as a  simple hierarchy.
2. Add `physics` for Inner `Listview`.
3. Set `mainaxis` size for `Column`
4. Wrap `Wordmeaning()` class with `Expanded`

   ```
   class NestedListView {
    build(){    
        return ListView.builder(
                  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        List<Meaning> innerList = data[index].meaning;
                        return Column(
                          children: [
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                              child: Text(data[index].type.toString().toUpperCase()),
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              child : ListView.builder(
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), //#2 Add this line
                                itemCount: innerList.length,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  final product = innerList[index];
                                  return Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                                    child: Container(
                                        color: Colors.grey,
                                        child: Column(
                                        mainAxisSize : MainAxisSize.max, // #3 Add this line
                                          children: [
                                            Text(product.description),
                                            Text(product.example),
                                          ]
                                        ))
                                  );
                                })
                             ])               
                        })
                   }    
   }
   ```

   // No change here

   ```
   class WordMeaning extends StatelessWidget {

        build(){
                List<Word> words = json.map((json) => Word.fromJson(json)).toList();    
                return NestedListView(data: words);
        }
   ```

   }

   ```
   class _SearchResultState extends State<SearchResult> {

        build(){
            return Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            body: SafeArea(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  SearchBox(),
                  WordDetails(),
                  const SizedBox(height: 5),
                  DictionaryUsersList(),
                  Expanded(
                    child : WordMeaning()    // #4 Wrap this with Expanded or Flexible
                    ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        );
    }
   ```

   }

This should build your UI as expected. Let me know if that works.

Comment: I have added all your codes, but getting the below error: `RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderSingleChildViewport#53737 relayoutBoundary=up11 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE`

Comment: I don't know what the issue is. If I create a sample and share, could you please have a look?

Comment: I have created a demo with my code, could you please check. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z9IfAFEGUhv4FGmrIQp5KFAeHO6hiXNb/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Size looks big. Try to share the source files alone ! Will try to help you .

Comment: Resolved the issue by removing all the Expanded widgets as suggested by Hamza.